# String was not recognised as a valid date time because day of the week was incorrect

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When changing my browser language to Italian and choosing any date from March 2020 and using Convert.toDateTime(date.Text) I am getting String was not recognised as a valid date time because the day of week was incorrect exception. Please review and help.

Thanks

Comment: What is in `date.Text`?

Answer (score 1):

*Convert.ToDateTime* uses the current culture of your machine to try the conversion from a string to a date. If your input string is not expressed in the current culture (or in the Invariant culture) then you need to give some help to [*Convert.ToDateTime*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToDateTime_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) passing the culture in which the date is formatted as a string.

So suppose that your textbox contains:

```
string data = "Martedì 18 Agosto 2020";
```

Then you can write

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("it");
DateTime t = Convert.ToDateTime(data, ci);
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `Covert.toDateTime()` is not able to parse any valid date in any language. I suggest you would stick to an ISO-8601 date string or Unix Timestamp to send it from and to the browser. In the example in the [documentation of the function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime?view=netcore-3.1#System_Convert_ToDateTime_System_String_) you see some example dates which can and cannot be parsed. I personally prefer Unix Timestamps, however you would need to use a library in your browser like `momentjs` to make it a date object again. In case you want to use strings, you might want to stick to this format:

```cs
// Convert a string returned by DateTime.ToString("o").
dateString = "2009-05-01T07:54:59.9843750-04:00";
Convert.toDateTime(dateString);
```